# Panda astype not converting column to int even when using errors=ignore

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have the following DF

```
    ID
0   1.0
1   555555.0
2   NaN
3   200.0
```

When I try to convert the ID column to Int64 I got the following error:

```
Cannot convert non-finite values (NA or inf) to integer
```

I've used the following code to solve this problem:

```
df["ID"] = df["ID"].astype('int64', errors='ignore')
```

Although, when I use the above code my ID column persists with `float64` type.

Any tip to solve this problem?

Comment: What do you want to do with this column? Numeric computation or just display?

Comment: Just convert the IDs to int type to save in a CSV file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `pd.Int64DType64` instead of `np.int64`:

```
df['ID'] = df['ID'].fillna(pd.NA).astype(pd.Int64Dtype())
```

Output:

```
>>> df
       ID
0       1
1  555555
2    <NA>
3     200

>>> df['ID'].dtype
Int64Dtype()

>>> df['ID'] + 10
0        11
1    555565
2      <NA>
3       210
Name: ID, dtype: Int64

>>> print(df.to_csv(index=False))
ID
1
555555
""
200
```

Comment: Thank you, your answer solved my problem!